# Auto numbering the plots with rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have found [this page](https://rpubs.com/ajlyons/autonumfigs) to number and reference plots. It worked fine, however recently I upgrade rstudio to Version 0.99.902 and deleted the cache and no longer translates the Rmd to html. I used to use `cache = TRUE` but now I want to recompile it from scratch however I get an error on the firs code chunk which starts with:

````
```{r data.analysis, fig.cap=fig$cap("analysi", "Information in each column")}
meta.info <- as.data.frame(lapply(col.data, na.replace))
variable.info <- sapply(meta.info, filter.info)
````

The error is:

```
label: data.analysis (with options) 
List of 1
 $ fig.cap: language fig$cap("analysi", "Information in each column")

Quitting from lines 218-224 (IEO_report.Rmd) 
Error in ref[[refName]] <<- i : object 'ref' not found
```

I get this error both in rstudio and when using `knit("file.Rmd", "file.md")` from base R, so I don't think it is a rstudio error.

But can compile those that use the following options:

````
```{r data.analysis, fig.cap="\\label{fig:col.data.analysis}Figure 1."}
````

I thought that I would need to change the order of the fig option to make available `ref` before `cap` but that didn't worked.

```
fig <- local({
    i <- 0
    list(
        cap=function(refName, text, center=FALSE, col="black", inline=FALSE) {
            i <<- i + 1
            ref[[refName]] <<- i
            css_ctr <- ""
            if (center) css_ctr <- "text-align:center; display:inline-block; width:100%;"
            cap_txt <- paste0("<span style=\"color:", col, "; ", css_ctr, "\">Figure ", i, ": ", text , "</span>")
            anchor <- paste0("<a name=\"", refName, "\"></a>")
            if (inline) {
                paste0(anchor, cap_txt)    
            } else {
                list(anchor=anchor, cap_txt=cap_txt)
            }
        },

        ref=function(refName, link=FALSE, checkRef=TRUE) {

            ## This function puts in a cross reference to a caption. You refer to the
            ## caption with the refName that was passed to fig$cap() (not the code chunk name).
            ## The cross reference can be hyperlinked.

            if (checkRef && !refName %in% names(ref)) stop(paste0("fig$ref() error: ", refName, " not found"))
            if (link) {
                paste0("<A HREF=\"#", refName, "\">Figure ", ref[[refName]], "</A>")
            } else {
                paste0("Figure ", ref[[refName]])
            }
        },

        ref_all=function(){
            ## For debugging
            ref
        })
})
```

How should I change this code to work as expected? (And why it doesn't work on the expected behavior? Did some update on the knitr package broke this?

Comment: You may try https://bookdown.org